# Visualization of rotation in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, visualization

I am trying to visualize the following rotation of $\mathbb R^3$, but it is very difficult. I want to get the answer by intuition, and not by using the Rodrigues rotation formula or conjugation of matrices, etc.

Help please.

**Problem statement:** Determine the matrix that represents the following rotation of $\mathbb R^3$: an angle of $\pi/2$ about the fixed axis containing the vector $(1,1,0)^t$

Here is what I have tried in my diagram:

[image: Coordinate axes]

Should I find a 3x3 rotation matrix $A$ such that $A(1,1,0)^t=(-1,1,0)^t$?

By working out the problem using the conjugate matrices, I end up getting the answer to be:

A = \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 & 0.5 & 0.5 & \\ 0.5 & 0.5 & -\sqrt(2)/2\\ -\sqrt(2)/2 & \sqrt(2)/2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

This answer is not at all intuitive.

Comment: If $\vec v$ is on the axis or rotation, then surely $A \vec v = \vec v$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are rotating around an axis, all points on that axis will remain the same after transformation. (e.g. If you rotate around $(1,1,0)^t$, $\alpha(1,1,0)^t = A \alpha(1,1,0)^t ,\forall \alpha \in \Bbb R$)

It may help to start by thinking of rotation about a different axis. ($\hat y$, for example)
What happens to the points upon rotation around this axis? Which change? Which remain the same? Can you create a transformation matrix for this simpler case?

Answer (score 0):

The matrix corresponding to this transformation does the following to the orthogonal basis consisting of $\{(1,1,0),(-1,1,2),(1,-1,1)\}$ -- basically guessed here:

The vector $(1,1,0)$ gets sent to itself.
The vector $(-1,1,2)$ gets mapped to $(1,-1,1)$.
The vector $(1,-1,1)$ gets mapped to  $-(-1,1,2)$.

These follow from geometric intuition given by your picture above.

Therefore, **in this basis**, $A$ is simple the matrix
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}

So, if you want to describe this matrix in usual basis, you apply the change of basis matrix to this matrix.